# PHP login/index error

Tags: php

My login form works fine but on my index page I have a script that redirects the user to login if not logged in but it gives me an error, also if i remove the code it'll work fine
 Here's the code:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="") {
 header("Location: index.php");
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="") {
 header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean. Not sure why you compare it to `!= ""`.

Comment: @R.Chappell 'Failed to open page'

Comment: If this is your index.php file, why are you redirecting to it again? Sounds like you're stuck in an infinite loop. Your index page is constantly redirecting to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You need only the second condition:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Adding the first condition it will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @oceanman It is strange that you used my answer to fix your issue but you accepted another answer with the same thing but no explanation.. that's not right..

Answer (score 2):

As I can see here, you are try to check existent the index in a wrong way, check this code instead

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

**UPDATE**
as mentioned in comments, don't do this in index.php. if you are in index.php remove else block

Comment: This still is affected by the infinite loop bug if it's added to the index page.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **else** instead another **if**